# Pop not reducing array.length after logical operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, logical-operators

I have this bizzare behavior which I've never seen and don't understand. I'm going through an array using arrayname.length as the control for a while loop. Which normally works as expected but this particular case creates an endless loop when the length of the array is not reduced beyond the first iteration.

```
while( data.length > 0){
    finalCheck = finalCheck && data.pop();
}
```

Here, the initial length is 4 and finalCheck starts at true. The first couple array elements are false.

As expected on first iteration, finalCheck becomes false and data.length becomes 3 but then for every iteration afterwards data.length stays at 3... does anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`finalCheck` becomes false at some point, causing `data.pop()` to not be executed. Then, the loop becomes infinite.

`data.pop()` returns the removed element from the array. If it's a value evaluating to false, no elements will be removed at the next iteration, causing `data.length` to always be higher than zero.

```
var data = [0, 1], finalCheck = false;
while( data.length > 0){
    finalCheck = finalCheck && data.pop(); //Hello infinite loop
}
```

In the previously shown example, `finalCheck` is already `false` before the iteration, causing `data.pop()` to never be executed. Even if `finalCheck` is initialized at `true`, `finalCheck` will be set to zero, and be stuck again.

To fix your code, you should AT LEAST use:

```
while( data.length > 0 && finalCheck){
    finalCheck = data.pop(); //Bye infinite loop
}
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is nice. This gives the behavior I was expecting. *smacks forehead* but I'm surprised javascript treats AND as a condition in this context.

Comment: logical operators will always act, well, logical ;) What did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

If `finalCheck` becomes false, why should `data.pop()` ever need to execute? The JavaScript interpreter is correctly short-circuiting and not evaluating the right side of the expression.

If you're trying to wait until `finalCheck` is true, you probably want to use the `||` operator instead:

```
finalCheck = false; // initially anyway
while( data.length > 0 && !finalCheck){
    finalCheck = finalCheck || data.pop();
}
```

You also need to make sure you break out of the loop when you've hit your terminating condition!

Comment: oh, I hadn't thought of that because I'm not using the "AND" operator in the context of a condition. I want it to evaluate the two values using a logical "AND". Thanks this helps a lot. I guess I'm still not accustomed to some quirks of interpreted languages.

Comment: If you want to evaluate both sides, just execute the statements outside the conditional and evaluate the conditional operator of the results: `result = data.pop(); finalCheck = finalCheck && result;`

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the loop uses the short-circuit `&&` operator, so `pop` won't be called any more as soon as `finalCheck` is false.

You can just skip out of the loop as soon as `finalCheck` becomes false. Once it's false it won't ever become true again, so there is no reason to continue at that point:

```
while (finalCheck && data.length > 0) {
  finalCheck = finalCheck && data.pop();
}
```

Comment: `&=` is equivalent to `finalCheck = finalCheck & data.pop()`, which is a bitwise operator. This piece of code does not have the same result as `finalCheck = finalCheck && data.pop()`.

Comment: @RobW: Yes, you are right. I removed that part from the answer.